# @Requestbody mapping to inherited subclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a class Vehicle in my Java Program.
The class Cab inherits from Vehicle.

In my controller I have a post mapping for adding new cabs to the Vehicles array.

```
@PostMapping("/vehicles/add/cab")
public void addCab(@RequestBody Cab cab) {
    System.out.println(cab);
    cc.addVehicle(cab);
}
```

The contractor of Cab looks like this.

```
public Cab(String licensePlate, double basePricePerKm, double horsePower)
```

I tried printing the Object in the RequestBody to the console, it had all the properties of the constructor

```
{
"licensePlate": "GR-221CH",
"basePricePerKm": 3.0,
"horsePower": 25.5
}
```

However I get an error

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.demo3.Cab.Cab`

How do I do it right/resolve this error?

Comment: can you add default constructor and getters and setters for the given fields

Comment: Could you add code for the Car POJO please

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your controller consumes `application/json`. So behind the scenes, by default Spring is attempting to use Jackson Databind to map fields into your `Cab` object. Databind has requirements for how the class is written to allow values to be bound to objects.

In the simplest case, you're writing a POJO:

- Add a public default (no-arg) constructor. You can still have additional constructors if they suit your purposes, e.g. test fixturing.
- Add `public` getters and setters.  (Jackson can also bind to a public field.)

By default, Jackson will find setters from `Cab` and its `Vehicle` superclass (and any other classes above that).  So if the three POJO properties you've listed really belong to `Vehicle`, they should get bound there, all without using your 3-arg constructor. Then you can add `Cab`-specific properties to `Cab`, also using property binding.

There are a bunch of annotations you can use to customize how values are bound, e.g. mapping differing JSON attribute names to your POJO properties, or ignoring certain properties.

See [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) for details. There is even a way to map JSON values into a constructor, though I personally wouldn't use it -- yet another thing to maintain if the object model changes, especially when inheritance is a factor.

In the case that your body isn't JSON, Spring has several other `HttpMessageConverter` implementations, which of course are configurable.  See Spring's [Rest Message Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-message-conversion) docs.